# SonarQube 6.2 installation error on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, sonarqube, failed-installation

I am trying to install SonarQube 6.2 on Windows 10.
I am getting this error when I run startSOnar.bat:

```
2016.12.27 14:31:27 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.12.27 14:31:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\Sonar\sonarqube-6.2\web
2016.12.27 14:31:29 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.27 14:31:29 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.12.27 14:31:34 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Cyborg X] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2016.12.27 14:31:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2016.12.27 14:31:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.2 / 4a28f29f95254b58f3cf0a0871bc632e998403f5
2016.12.27 14:31:37 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.12.27 14:31:37 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: C:\Sonar\sonarqube-6.2\data
2016.12.27 14:31:37 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.12.27 14:31:38 WARN  web[][o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: C:\Sonar\sonarqube-6.2
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.5.1.522 / 9a3e26d7843b226a6772b5103e72120c3003d958
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 4.3.0.7717 / de5bafc9f2e40a91d419c774fffc6d6061ba8da5
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.18.0.3454 / c276cc8dfeb99da907f2ec76ede9f59836da2bc9
2016.12.27 14:31:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2016.12.27 14:31:43 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2016.12.27 14:31:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2016.12.27 14:31:48 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2016.12.27 14:31:48 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2016.12.27 14:31:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2016.12.27 14:31:50 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service stopped
2016.12.27 14:31:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database stopped
2016.12.27 14:31:51 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Severity of rule [repository=squid, key=S00105] is not correct: MİNOR
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.api.server.rule.RulesDefinition$NewRule.setSeverity(RulesDefinition.java:712)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaRulesDefinition.addMetadata(JavaRulesDefinition.java:102)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaRulesDefinition.ruleMetadata(JavaRulesDefinition.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaRulesDefinition.newRule(JavaRulesDefinition.java:83)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaRulesDefinition.define(JavaRulesDefinition.java:59)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RuleDefinitionsLoader.load(RuleDefinitionsLoader.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.start(RegisterRules.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:88)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:40)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:70)
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:67)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:201)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016.12.27 14:31:51 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.12.27 14:31:51 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.12.27 14:31:51 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.27 14:31:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.12.27 14:31:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.12.27 14:31:51 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:46)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
2016.12.27 14:31:51 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.27 14:31:52 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProto`enter code here`col] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.27 14:31:52 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.27 14:31:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
```

Comment: The error log is illegible. Please format it well.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

- You can edit your Db configuration opening cloesed parameter on ‪     your_basesonar_dir\conf\sonar.properties.For example open Mysql confs to use as a DB.
- Or you can set "sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Duser.language=en" parameter on your_basesonar_dir\conf\sonar.properties to avoid language corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Severity of rule [repository=squid, key=S00105] is not correct: MİNOR.
```

The severity should be MINOR, not MİNOR (wrong "I").

As you're using H2, you should try to remove the data folder and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Add jvm parameter to start in english (to prevent uppercase turkish character issues)

sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError **-Duser.language=en**